# mysql bin-log.index not found

Tags: mysql, logs

I moved my bin-logs to a different folder:

```
log-bin = /storage/mysql/bin-log
log-bin-index = /storage/mysql/bin-log.index
```

When I try to start mysqld I get this:

```
/usr/libexec/mysqld: File '/storage/mysql/bin-log.index' not found (Errcode: 13)
```

Permissions for the files and directory are fine, `sudo -u mysql touch /storage/mysql/bin-log.index` is working fine and there is no apparmor installed.

Any ideas what could cause this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SELinux was installed and it didn't allow access to those files.

Disabling it solves the problem.

Comment: For Ubuntu users it is probably AppArmor. Edit /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld and add TWO lines: the path and the path with a wildcard, both rw.

Comment: Stop disabling SELinux! [Every time you run setenforce 0, you make Dan Walsh weep. Dan is a nice guy and he certainly doesn't deserve that.](https://stopdisablingselinux.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Based on this documentation from Red Hat: [Chapter 3. SELinux Contexts](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/chap-security-enhanced_linux-selinux_contexts) and `man page` reading:

I want to have logfiles in `/var/log/mysql` instead of `/var/log/mariadb` and leave SELinux enabled.

The newly created log directory `/var/log/mysql` will by default be unaccessible to MySQL server due to SELinux.

So:

`grep` for string `setroubleshoot` in `/var/log/` and run the indicated `sealert` commands to find details on the actual SELinux problem you observe.

For example:

```
sealert -l 141804b3-9ae5-4484-be0b-741fc558ff6d
SELinux is preventing /usr/libexec/mysqld from 'read, write' accesses on the file bin_hull03.index.

*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that mysqld should be allowed read write access on the bin_hull03.index file by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'mysqld' --raw | audit2allow -M my-mysqld
# semodule -i my-mysqld.pp


Additional Information:
...
```

This is not necessarily helpful in this case.

Use `ls -lZ` to find out what the context of `/var/log/mysql` is relative to `/var/log/mariadb`:

```
# ls -lZ /var/log/mysql /var/log/mariadb
drwxrwx---. root mysql unconfined_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0 mysql
drwxr-x---. mysql mysql system_u:object_r:mysqld_log_t:s0 mariadb
```

Now adapt the file context of the tree `/var/log/mysql`.

Check what its supposed value is by retrieving the context for `/var/log/mariadb` from the SELinux config database:

```
# semanage fcontext --list | egrep '/var/log/(mysql|mariadb)'
/var/log/mysql.*       regular file  system_u:object_r:mysqld_log_t:s0 
/var/log/mysql(/.*)?   all files     system_u:object_r:mysqld_log_t:s0
```

Add an entry to the SELinux settings database to define the context of the new file tree:

```
# semanage fcontext --add -s system_u -t mysqld_log_t  '/var/log/mysql(/.*)?'
semanage fcontext --list | egrep '/var/log/(mysql|mariadb)'
/var/log/mysql.*        regular file   system_u:object_r:mysqld_log_t:s0 
/var/log/mariadb(/.*)?  all files      system_u:object_r:mysqld_log_t:s0 
/var/log/mysql(/.*)?    all files      system_u:object_r:mysqld_log_t:s
```

Set SELinux attributes recursively on the new file tree itself:

```
restorecon -r -F /var/log/mysql/
```

This gives what we want:

```
# ls -lZR /var/log/mysql/
/var/log/mysql/:
drwxrwx---. root  mysql system_u:object_r:mysqld_log_t:s0 binary
drwxrwx---. root  mysql system_u:object_r:mysqld_log_t:s0 general
-rw-rw----. mysql mysql system_u:object_r:mysqld_log_t:s0 mysqld_safe_log.err
drwxrwx---. root  mysql system_u:object_r:mysqld_log_t:s0 relay
-rw-rw----. mysql mysql system_u:object_r:mysqld_log_t:s0 server.err
drwxrwx---. root  mysql system_u:object_r:mysqld_log_t:s0 slow

/var/log/mysql/binary:
-rw-rw----. mysql mysql system_u:object_r:mysqld_log_t:s0 bin_hull03.000001
-rw-rw----. mysql mysql system_u:object_r:mysqld_log_t:s0 bin_hull03.000002
-rw-rw----. mysql mysql system_u:object_r:mysqld_log_t:s0 bin_hull03.index

/var/log/mysql/general:

/var/log/mysql/relay:

/var/log/mysql/slow:
```