# How to set selinux permission for non-standard mysql bin log path?

Tags: mysql, linux, binlog

By default, mysql bin log works in folder /var/log/mysql. but moving to any other share such /mylogs/mysql gives permission error.

Below is the exact message:

usr/sbin/mysqld: File '/mylogs/mysql/mysql-bin.index' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)

how to fix this without disabling selinux?

There is similar problem in the link below but solution is not acceptable as I cannot disable SELinux. 
[mysql bin-log.index not found](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12346/mysql-bin-log-index-not-found)

Answer (score 3):

To set mysql selinux on a directory you can:

`semanage fcontext -a -t mysqld_db_t "/yourdirectory(/.*)?"`

then

`restorecon -Rv /yourdirectory`

Also check the mysql user has permissions on your directory:

`ls -l`

Set permissions if needed:

`chown -R mysql:mysql /yourdirectory`

Comment: question if you dont mind. Something like mean the result will not fix the issue for sure or not sure about the syntax.

Comment: Well this is how I would try add the mysql policy to selinux. so mysql has permissions to do filesystem operations. something to try, shouldn't do any harm